# Tridion 2011 SP1 WebDAV connecting to the wrong folder

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1, webdav

I have a client who is having trouble connecting to their Tridion installation via WebDAV. After trying to fix this and resetting permissions I am once again able to get them connected. However, instead of connecting to a location that contains a folder for each publication in Tridion we get a different folder. They are instead seeing the folder that contains the web config and other files that pertain to the WebDAV part of Tridion. I am not sure why we are getting this instead of the expected set of folders for publications. I am fairly new to Tridion still so this may be something I have simply over looked.

We are running this on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7

Comment: Can you share how you're connecting, e.g. url, mapping the drive and OS your client is using?

Comment: Any chance the user forgot to add /webdav to the end when configuring the network location?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a minor configuration setting within your IIS.

There's some great answers [in this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/487/configure-webdav-on-the-server) that I think will help you work this out, or you can review your installation against the [online documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-34C99379-BA36-4816-A485-2FE49C1D88D8)