# Unable to write in WebDAV drive

Tags: 2011-sp1, webdav

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1  and was trying to copy xml files/binaries from my local machine to WebDAV network drive. But I am getting below error message.

> You need permission to perform this action

Please let me know if I am missing some part in WebDAV configuration. I am using IIS 7.5 on my server machine, So I guess there is no added need for configuring IIS.

I have mapped WebDAV network drive on win 7.

Can anyone suggest why exactly am I getting such error message?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you have performed all steps for installing webdav? There should be no special characters in the path. Additionally, you need to enable webdav in IIS as suggeseted here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/498/644

Comment: How can we let you know if you are missing some part in your WebDAV configuration, when we don't know that configuration? You are giving a very limited amount of information, it would be helpful if you supply some more like what the exact error message is in the Tridion event log etc.

Comment: Have you checked event logs whenever WebDAV deployment is failing with error "you need permission to perform this action".

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you haven't got the correct permissions in Tridion. To check this, make sure you are in the publication that you think you are, and try to use the Tridion Explorer GUI to create a component in the same folder that you're using via webdav.

Don't forget to check that you are using the correct account.

If all that is correct, then it's probably an impersonation issue.

Comment: I am able to create components, scehma etc in Tridion via console with same credentials.
I don't think it is happening because of account permission as I am owning administrator rights in CME.